# Watch OS2 - performSelector: does not work in controller

Tags: objective-c, watchkit, watchos

I'm trying to call a method + delay inside a Watch OS2 controller (`WKInterfaceController`) with delay using:

`[self performSelector:@selector(createPages) withObject:nil afterDelay:3.0];`

And the method:

```
- (void) createPages {
    NSLog(@"Creating pages");
}
```

The `createPages` method is never called. Not seeing any errors in the console. Seems like it's completely ignoring it. Does anyone know why this might be happening?

Thanks!

G

Comment: where did you call createPages with performSelector? The time the function is called after delay sometimes will delay itself.  But it should work if it is in awakeWithContext or willActivate.

Comment: @tipsywacky calling this in `willActivate`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Grand Central Dispatch is a better approach for this kind of thing, and it also will work with statically dispatched methods if you're using Swift.  You can execute some code after 3 seconds like this:

```
dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(3.0 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [self createPages];
});
```

Check out the [Concurrency Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091) for more information.

Comment: Thanks! Will use GCD. Would still like to know why performSelector is failing though.

Comment: From the code you posted, the only guess I have is that self is not the class where the createPages implementation is.  But that's just speculation since I can't see where all the code is from.

Comment: The same issue with performSelector. Works fine in WatchOS 1 and doesn't work in WatchOS2